# Why the ruby code will generate an ArgumentError?

Tags: ruby, arguments

Hi I'm working on Ruby Koans. I was wondering why the `ArgumentError`would be raised if the `Dog6.new` is returned in the code down below?

```
class Dog6
  attr_reader :name 
  def initialize(initial_name)
    @name = initial_name 
  end
end

def test_initialize_provides_initial_values_for_instance_variables
  fido = Dog6.new("Fido")
  assert_equal "Fido", fido.name
end

def test_args_to_new_must_match_initialize
  assert_raise(ArgumentError) do
    Dog6.new
  end
end
```

Is it because `Dog6.new`doesn't have any arguments? Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct.

`Dog6.new` implicitly calls `Dog6#initialize` to initialize the newly created instance (one might think about [`MyClass#initialize`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Class.html#method-i-new) as about the constructor for this class,) which apparently has one *required* argument. Since no argument was given to the call to `Dog6.new`, the `ArgumentError` is being raised.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Now I understand :)

Answer (score 1):

Just adding that if you want to have a constructor with no arguments (after all - some dogs don't have a name....) you could have a default value for the name parameter.

```
def initialize(name = nil)
  @name = name
end
```

Comment: Adding default value will **break the test**. It is by no mean an applicable solution.

Comment: Indeed! You'll have to change the tests first obviously. :-)

Comment: I would rather remove that test though. Testing for all possible ArgumentError's does not seem constructive to me.

Answer (score 0):

In the initializer for the `Dog6` class, `initial_name` is defined as a parameter required for object construction. If this class were to be instantiated without this argument, an `ArgumentError` would be raised because the class definition has a method signature such that `Dog6.new` is invalid, like you guessed. In this case the error you would see would be:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

Read more about the ArgumentError exception [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/ArgumentError.html).